# JQuery datepicker odd behaviour in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, binding, datepicker

I couldn't find a complete solution for using JQuery date picker in MVC3 and from what I found on different pages I came up with my solution which still does not work as I want it to.
I have the following:

The model:

```
public class Some
{
    [Display(Name = "DateCreated", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName =      "RequiredField")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date non valid.")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "NotSpecified", DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy.}")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

I am decorating the property cause I want the client and the server side validation and text.

I am using the Home controller for this example and I have:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Some model = new Some { DateCreated = DateTime.Now };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Some model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

The view:

```
@model TestDatePicker.Models.Some

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated)
  </div>

  <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </p>
}
```

And a custom template for rendering the field with DateTime type:

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime>

@{
    string controlName = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    string controlId = controlName.Replace(".", "_");

    if ( Model.HasValue ) {
        @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy.}", Model.Value), new { @class = "textbox", name = controlName })
    }
    else {
        @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy.}", DateTime.Now), new { @class = "textbox", name = controlName })
    }
  }

}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $(".textbox").datepicker
           ({
              dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy.',
              showStatus: true,
              showWeeks: true,
              highlightWeek: true,
              numberOfMonths: 1,
              showAnim: "scale",
              showOptions: {
                  origin: ["top", "left"]
              },
              onClose: function () {
                  $(this).valid();
              }
          });
  });
</script>
```

What is happening with this code?
The value for the DateTime filed is assigned in the custom template and it is shown as today's date.

1. However, on clicking the Save button, in the [HttpPost] Index method I see that the passed in model does not hold the today's date value but 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM?
2. Then the Model.IsValid does not pass with the message ***The value '26.05.2012.' is not valid for Date created.***??? Seems even stranger to me!
3. The above message is displayed on the page instead of my custom message:
   [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date non valid.")]

Interesting this is that if you use the datepicker and select a data from it, you get the property in the model populated. And Model.IsValid is TRUE.

This is how the html for the input control looks like:

```
<input class="textbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="Requred field" id="DateCreated" name="DateCreated" type="text" value="26.05.2012." />
```

[image: This is on page load]

[image: This is when just clicking Save after page loads]

[image: This is the result, not taking my custom error message assigned to Model]

Is the JQueryUI date picker not the best choice for ASP.NET MVC? It seems that, whit this solution of the custom template that I see all over the net, the basic MVC stuff is not even working? Does anyone know of any complete tutorial on doing this? I can't be the first person facing these problems.

Thank you.

I have downloaded the code that is created in [the blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx) everyone refers to when talking about MVC3 and datepicker and the SAME thing is happening there!

Answer (score 2):

Theres nothing in your template that binds between your model and the datetime value you are providing.

When a form is submited, mvc needs to know how to fill the Some object with the values from the form. This works with standart editors, because they use the binded propety name as the id/name for the client side inputs. You didnt do this with your custom editor, and therefor when the form is submited, theres no way for mvc to tell your custom editor actually supplies the DateCreated property.

Add the name / id attributes to the underlying input in your editor to make this work (or use the standart provided editor, and the look at the html source of ur page in the browser / any kind of a networking sniffer to see exactly how it works)

**EDIT: my complete version of the code, that works**

model:

```
  public class Some 
{ 
    [Display(Name = "DateCreated")]     
    [Required(ErrorMessage="failed")]    
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date non valid.")]    
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "NotSpecified", DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy.}")]     
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } }
```

controller:

```
    public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        Some model = new Some { DateCreated = DateTime.Now }; 
        return View(model); 
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Some model) 
    { 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
        }
        return View(model); 
    } 

}
```

index view:

```
@model Some  
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
      <div class="editor-label">     
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated)  
      </div>   
      <div class="editor-field">     
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated)  
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated)   
      </div>    
       <p>     
         <input type="submit" value="Save" />  
      </p> 
}
```

date editor:

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
@{     
  string controlName = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;     
  string controlId = controlName.Replace(".", "_");      
  if ( Model.HasValue )
  {        
      @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy.}", Model.Value), 
       new {@class "textbox", name = controlName })     
  }     
  else
  {         
     @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy.}", DateTime.Now), 
     new { @class = "textbox", name = controlName })    
  }  
} 

          <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {
                  $(".textbox").datepicker({
                      dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy.',
                      showStatus: true,
                      showWeeks: true,
                      highlightWeek: true,
                      numberOfMonths: 1,
                      showAnim: "scale",
                      showOptions: { origin: ["top", "left"] },
                      onClose: function () { $(this).valid(); } 
                  });
              }); 
               </script>
```

included scripts:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it works 100% on my side, with our without the jquery datepicker. I change the usage of the attributes a tiny bit, and didnt provide resources for them. as far as i understand, btw, the DataType attribute is useless in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please look at my edited template and the change I have added for the id attribute. I does not fix the problem.

Comment: its name that you need, not id (id is used mainly for javascript). did you add it as well? the name attribute is what used in the world of http to identify the form fields, when they are submited to thr server. [this post](http://develoq.net/2011/asp-net-mvc-model-binders-and-how-to-create-custom-model-binder/) explains this well, i believe.

Comment: Thanks for the post, it's a great resource. I voted one on that comment. Please look at the updated code in my question. I think that the first load of the page needs some "hacking" cause after you select a value from the datepicker it works fine.

Comment: What happens if you dont? the only thing i can see that differs is the formating you are using (you format at first as dd.mm.yyyy. and in the jquery datepicker as dd.mm.yy)

Comment: The formatting actually results in the same format. The datepicker formatting string is different. But I don't understand what  are you asking me, if I don't do what? Do not select the value from the datepicker? It happens what I have described in the question: the property of the model is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM and the Model.IsValid fails with the message The value '26.05.2012.' is not valid for Date created. And 16.05.2012. is assigned in the template code on page load.

Comment: this works perfectly on my side, i think you maybe missed something while copy - pasting the code here. i copied the lines you posted, and it works as expected..

Comment: When the page loads just click Save btn. Do nothing with datepicker. And look at the value of the property in the model. As in my screen shots.

Comment: I copy - pasted your code and it work perfectly, both with and without the date picker. I think you missed something in your copy pastes. jst check again whether this is the code ur running as well.. good luck

Comment: I can't believe it. I did 3 different examples and in every one I got the same thing. Even with the code from the blog post in the question. I don't know what to do now. Can you somehow send me your whole solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11783/discussion-between-yavgenyp-and-elector)

Comment: Hi there. Any luck sending it? I don't see you on the chat so I posting here. Thank you